# Could not find a matching version of package magento/extension-b2b. Check the package spelling

Tags: magento2, b2b

When I am trying to install B2B module for the enterprise edition for version 2.4.1 getting this error
"Could not find a matching version of package magento/extension-b2b. Check the package spelling, your version constraint, and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

unable to debug the issue and tried with updated composer also.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the public and private I was using in auth.json.
tried with correct keys and module installed now.